# ZFS Scrubbing on Ubuntu - System Performance Hack

Tags: bash, ubuntu, zfs

Ubuntu with ZFS file systems (zfsutils-linux) starts zfs scrubbing on second Sunday of every month. The scrub one-liner is in the /etc/cron.d/zfsutils-linux file. I was not aware of this behavior until I started having performance issues due to high IO. After poking around some, I had to write my own BASH script in order to modify this behavior. ZFS scrubbing is still necessary, but I wanted to scrub only a couple of file systems at a time. The script is posted below. Does anyone have a more elegant solution? It works for now but feels like a hack.

```
# Declaring the array to store zpools.
declare -a myZpools

# Populating the array with system zpools.
while read line;
do
  myZpools+=($line)
done <<< "$(/sbin/zpool list | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | grep -v NAME)"

# Length of the array is saved in totalPools variable
totalPools="${#myZpools[@]}"
# Dividing total number of zpools into five portions. The hard-coded denominator can be changed to any desired value. Smaller denominator yields bigger zpool portions to scan.
let portion=$totalPools/5 

# If input parameter is not specified, or if it is outside of boundaries of the array length, set it to the beginning of the array.
if ( [ -z $1 ] || [ $1 -ge $totalPools ] )
then
   day=0
else
   day=$1
fi

# Execute the scrubs.
/sbin/zpool scrub ${myZpools[@]:$day:$portion} &
```

Comment: I wouldn't spend much more time on this, it seems very good. You could clean up any syntax issues flagged by pasting it a https://shellcheck.net and include a `#!/bin/bash` as the first line. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Shellcheck.net is very helpful. I will definitely use it.